# Date difference on Atom dates?

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

I have 2 dates that I would like to get the difference of using the [date_diff function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php).

This is the code I am running:

```
$starttime=DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:sP",'2014-10-08T22:03:51.579+02:00');

$stoptime=DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:sP",'2014-10-08T22:04:59.811+02:00');

$interval = date_diff($starttime, $stoptime);

$interval->format("%i %s");
```

This should return a string from the date calculation with '01:08'

If it was calculating correctly but something seems to be wrong with the creation of the dates I think, the var_dump of the `$starttime` and `$stoptime` return FALSE which according to the doc means that the datetime object can't be created. Am I specifying the wrong format for my date/time string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made it more complex than it needs to be. `DateTime()` can handle that date format so skip using `createFromFormat()`:

```
$starttime= new DateTime('2014-10-08T22:03:51.579+02:00');
$stoptime= new DateTime('2014-10-08T22:04:59.811+02:00');
$interval = date_diff($starttime, $stoptime);
echo $interval->format("%i:%S");
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/205806)

Also, use `%S` to get leading zeros for your seconds.